# how to retrive data from the database based on a value of the cell of the datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a datagridview  which shows the list of customers details such as customer id, name ,etc etc.when i click on a particular customers row  and then click on a button  i want the customer id of that customer to be stored in a string which will then be used to retrieve the menu choices of the customer using an MySQL command.. example select * from menu where customerid=(string obtained from datagridview)

Comment: Your question is how to get the value from the clicked cell?

Comment: yes wen i click on the row the customer id of that row should be stored in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        int selectedrowindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = datagridview1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  
        string CustumerID = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["column name"].Value);           
    }
}
```

or this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int SelectedRowndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    string CustumerID= dataGridView1.Rows[SelectedRowndex].Cells["column name"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: a minor change in the requirement. first i select the row then on a button click the custid of the selected row should be stored in the string ... how can i acheive that.

Comment: thanks a lot i used the second part  of your answer and it worked perfectly